# React: setState on Child is updating parent's state on array property types

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and running into a weird issue. I
 have a Parent Child structure, where the child is a modal dialog. Below is some sample code I have

---

Parent State

```
this.state = { 
  features: [ 
    {index: 0, name: 'Feature 1', checked: true },
    {index: 1, name: 'Feature 2', checked: false },
    {index: 2, name: 'Feature 3', checked: false }
  ],
  showModal: false
};
```

Child is a modal with a list of check boxes. Here is the markup and the props I am passing to the Child component.

```
<Child showModal={this.state.showModal} close={this.closeModal} features={this.state.features}/>
```

There is a button on the page which switches the ***showModal*** flag to true which triggers the modal to show up. The modal displays a list of check boxes either checked or un-checked based on the ***checked*** flag on each feature. Also the modal has two button Save and Cancel.

Now when the user checks or un-checks a check box I am basically updating the ***checked*** flag to true or false and running a setState in the child component.

When the user closes the modal using the ***cancel*** button, which simply calls the  ***closeModal*** function via props which is setting ***showModal*** on parent state to false.

However, I see that the parent state's ***features*** property is updated with the updated check box states in the modal even though I haven't explicitly called for updating parent state or clicked the Save button, which is when I would like to update the parent's state.

Not sure what am I missing here.

Comment: It sounds reasonable, but it will be hard to help until you show the code of the parent and child components.

Comment: Can you add the implementation of Child component ? We can't tell you any answer like this.

Comment: Could you add the parent and child components code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like you need to copy array by value. Since objects are nested in your array, you are actually passing them by reference. You need to extract those objects before you modify them. When you want to save, you can save by modifying them by reference.

To replicate behavior:

```
let one = [{a: 1}, {b: 2}]
let two = one
two[0].a = 3
console.log(one) // [{a: 3}, {b: 2}]

let cpy = { ...one[0] }
cpy.a = 3
console.log(cpy) // {a: 3}
console.log(one) // [ { a: 1 }, { b: 2 } ]
```

To copy:

```
let newArray = one.map(obj => {
  return { ...obj }
})
```